Android OS 14 - Device is locked > Device is not waking up when injected event through the Accessibility service
I'm developing a private app where I'm using the Accessibility service to inject the various events remotely. One of the events is 'GLOBAL_ACTION_LOCK_SCREEN'. Using this event, a screen is getting locked. I'm able to inject this event successfully. Then one of the requirements is to wake up a locked device.  To do this, I woke up a locked device using the same event, 'GLOBAL_ACTION_LOCK_SCREEN'. Up to OS 13, this functioned (locking and unlocking a device) flawlessly. BUT from OS 14, the device unlocking (ie wakeup) using the same flag (GLOBAL_ACTION_LOCK_SCREEN) is no longer working.
I've searched the Accessibilityservice.java class to check whether any other event/flag is introduced, but no use. I have not found any other event/flag or way to wake up a device.
I'm looking for advice/guidance to unlock/wakeup a locked device using the Accessibility service. Looking forward to it.

OK. I'm concluding that this functionality works till OS 13. From OS 14, the flag 'GLOBAL_ACTION_LOCK_SCREEN' will not wake a device if device is locked.
